# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js) when using single-spa.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I Know that there is a lot of problem like this, but I'm seriously confused After read a lot of thread about this and still failed to solved my issue.

This is my first time using `single-spa` for micro frontend, but I got stuck in the first part.

this is the error I got:

> ERROR in ./single-spa.config.js
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>   Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js
>       at createDescriptor (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:178:11)
>       at items.map (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at createDescriptors (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
>       at createPresetDescriptors (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
>       at presets (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:47:19)
>       at mergeChainOpts (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
>       at D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at buildRootChain (D:\Gitpanda\singlespatest\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:120:29)
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

After read a lot of topic about this problem, i got a hunch maybe this error occur because of `babel` version but when I try to add and `instal` the preset since I use `babel-loader@8` i must instal `babel-core@7` but the error still there.

this is my **package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "single-spa": "^5.0.0",
    "single-spa-react": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
```

this is my **.babelrc:**

```
{
    "presets": [
      ["env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
        }
      }],
      "@babel/preset-env",
      ["react"]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "syntax-dynamic-import",
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

and this is my **webpack.config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
      // Set the single-spa config as the project entry point
        'single-spa.config': 'single-spa.config.js',
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              // Webpack style loader added so we can use materialize
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
            {
              // This plugin will allow us to use html templates when we get to the angularJS app
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    }, 
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            __dirname,
            'node_modules',
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // A webpack plugin to remove/clean the build folder(s) before building
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: [],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

If you wondering what I want to make, in fact I just follow this tutorial in [here](https://medium.com/@AndrewLocke/creating-a-single-spa-web-application-4e115802f474)

Can someone help me to solved this? I'm already confused about this